# pcre regex to get drupal 7 library version

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to ask a little help to find this text in a JavaScript file:

```
" * Version : 2.0.1.4"
```

This comment line storing the version number of a JavaScript library.
I would like to find it by a PCRE regex expression.
Can somebody help me?

It is needed to check the available version number of a Drupal 7 library.

Comment: Do you need to match or capture a certain part of that?

Comment: I need to capture the version name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation that you presented actually has an example of doing this.

> **pattern**: A string containing a regular expression (PCRE) to match the library version. For example: `@version\s+([0-9a-zA-Z\.-]+)@`. Note that the returned version is not the match of the entire pattern (i.e. `@version 1.2.3` in the above example) but the match of the first sub-pattern (i.e. `1.2.3`).

You should be able to modifiy the example regex as follows:

```
@Version\s+:\s+([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)@
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vU4nM3/5)

Comment: First of all I would like to thanks for everyone,
My problem is that the Live Demo works well but my function return with 0. `preg_match('@\sVersion\s:\s([0-9a-zA-Z\.-]+) @', 3, $version);`

Comment: `preg_match('/\sVersion\s:\s([0-9a-z.-]+)/i', $string, $version); echo $version[1];`

Comment: '3' was a mistake only, sorry for it and thanks for you for the solution it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the documentation you link to in the question:

```
@version\s+([0-9a-zA-Z\.-]+)@
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
" \* Version :(.*)?"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kQ7gT9/1)**

[image]

Comment: @praad glad to hear that. You can consider marking your question as solved.